# Purpose of id and client_id in RegisteredClient

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

while migrating my company's authorization server from former spring security oauth2 to the new authorization server project I recognized that the entity model has quitely changed. Especially the reference between the client details (registered client) and the authorization entity (formerly two tables for at and rt) has changed and the `client_id` property is not the foreign key anymore. The registerd client has a separate primary `id` properties.

So, I am asking if it was intentional to split `id` and `client_id` in separate properties and if there are any advantages doing so which i currently don't see?
For simplicity, I think i will use the same identifier for both of these properties, to make it easier for joins and looking into table e.g. checking authorizations.

Any other suggestions or opinions I am missing?

Comment: Isn't it likely that a single registered client gets authorized many times (once per connected user for instance)? Or even for a single client to be registered several times (once for authorization code flow and another one for client credentials)?

Comment: @ch4mp I think you are confusing it with the authorization table. Regarding one single client it is a 1:n, even for a single user. The client itself can have both configured, code flow and client credentials as grant types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward answer is that the `RegisteredClient` domain object is intended to be stored in a database (or other data store), where the primary key may be generated by the database itself.

See [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/c7b66e7a745f5b20cf36ba54484af32bd69c8280/samples/demo-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L136) which generates an `id` for demonstration purposes.

You can certainly decide what value goes into that field. If necessary, you can also [customize the data model](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/51ba7a8b958458d20804c2feda2518e6a9da0279/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/JdbcRegisteredClientRepositoryTests.java#L263-L264) and omit the `id` if you want `client_id` to be the PK.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about that the main reason is flexibility concerning the primary key of this domain object. Furthermore it will also be independent of the format. For instance, primary id is a `uuid` but `client_id` can be string identifier.

In our application, the registered client cannot be created publicly and is created by ourself. So, I thinks its safe to use the same id for both fields. And we already use custom repository for JPA.